# MSBuild SqlDataCompareTask in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-task

Does anyone know how to get the MSBuild "SqlDataCompareTask" target type working in VS2010 or TFS2010. It was previously included in the power tools which are not available for 2010.

I am trying to do a command line database sycnronization during a build action.